# QProcess execute bash and curl show no such file error?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I need to run a shell command `bash  <(curl -L https://get.acme.sh)` in QProcess, but it show `/bin/bash: <(curl: No such file or directory` error, i run the cmd shell well work.

**The code**

```py
class Process:
    def __init__(self):
        self.p = QProcess()
        self.p.setProcessEnvironment(QProcessEnvironment.systemEnvironment())
        self.p.finished.connect(self.on_process_finished)
        self.p.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.on_stdout)
        self.p.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.on_stderr)

    
    def start(self, program: str, arguments: typing.List[str] = []):
        self.p.setProgram(program)
        self.p.setArguments(arguments)
        self.p.start(program)
        self.p.waitForFinished(-1)
    
    def on_process_finished(self, exitCode, exitStatus):
        arguments = ' '.join(self.p.arguments())
        process_str = f'{self.p.program()} {arguments}'
        print_finish(f'Process: [{process_str}] execute finish!!!')
    
    def on_stdout(self):
        data = bytes(self.p.readAllStandardOutput())
        data_str = data.decode('utf-8')
        print(data_str)
        
    def on_stderr(self):
        data = bytes(self.p.readAllStandardError())
        data_str = data.decode('utf-8')
        print(data_str)

p = Process()
cmd = "bash  <(curl -L https://get.acme.sh)"
p.start(cmd)
```

Comment: Could you explain what your basic objective is? I ask to know what freedom I have to offer workarounds

Comment: @eyllanesc I want to use `QProcess`  to get  `acme.sh` and install it in shell cmd, python subprocess module work well, `QProcess` run with error.

Comment: @eyllanesc `QProcess` don't work perfect like `subprocess`, it sometimes show strange error.

Comment: QProcess is not a subprocess, so saying that one works or not based on the operation of the other is totally wrong.

Comment: @eyllanesc I try to run a single process and set out output to another process, it can work, it's mean that `QProcess` only can run one `shell cmd` only once.

Comment: I have been able to run this command but I am not getting feedback from the process since I need to run bash first, and the second command (your bash) creates a separate process that notifies the first process of anything. For example, when you open the terminal, a process is created that persists even after executing a command.

Answer (score 0):

try making cmd = "bash  <(curl -L https://get.acme.sh)"
a raw string like this cmd = **r**"bash  <(curl -L https://get.acme.sh)"
this gets around intepretation of special characters, which i think causes your issues.